# How can I integrate Vuex into a Storyblok plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, storyblok

I'm building a plugin for storyblok with vue.  I decided it would be easier to add state management to the plugin rather than an echo chamber of `$emit()` all the way back up the component tree.  I installed Vuex into my plugin and went to add it to the `main.js` file as instructed in a Vuex tutorial however my `main.js` file isn't set up like a regular Vue app's `main.js` file.

The tutorial tells us to do this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store' //our Vuex store

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    store, //passing in our store
    render: h =>(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

However my `main.js` file due to being a storyblok plugin looks like this

```
import Plugin from './Plugin.vue'
import store from './store'  //I have no clue where to put this in the code below :(

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {

  window.Fieldtype = Plugin
  let customComp = window.Storyblok.vue.extend(window.Fieldtype);
  window.Storyblok.vue.component('custom-plugin', customComp);
  window.StoryblokPluginRegistered = true;

} else {
  
  let init = Plugin.methods.initWith() 
  window.storyblok.field_types[init.plugin] = Plugin

}
```

As you can see the setup is totally different as it's geared towards injecting a Vue component into storyblok as a plugin rather than setting up a new Vue app.  Does anybody know what I should do here?

Comment: I would suggest you use a different state library without the Vue overhead. I can recommend DiffX. It's great, comes with a really good browser extension. https://github.com/jbjorge/diffx/tree/master/core ( you can use it as an node package or even use as `window.diffx` directly from a script tag if needed: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@diffx/core@2.0.3/dist/diffx.umd.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: how large of a community does DiffX have?  I'm already in over my head with things not many people know enough about to help me with lol.

Comment: It's unclear how the store is supposed to be used. Will it be used with other components? I don't deal with Storyblok but here it's obvious that global instance is in use, so it would be `window.Storyblok.vue.use(store)`. The code uses Vue 2 and globals. See https://github.com/storyblok/storyblok-vue/issues/7 . Vuex isn't the only alternative to $emit. You may not need Vuex at all. Vue already has everything you need to set up your own global store - provide/inject and reactive objects.

Comment: I happen to know the creator of DiffX, it's a new project by a very smart guy who has been very responsive to questions (mine and other's) I bet you'd get an answer directly from the creator in no time if you file an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for the info.  I looked into it last night and saw how we can use the composition API to build it.  However I haven't found anything with them chaining multiple modules into one main module.  I've seen examples of the modules being isolated basically as a bunch of micro stores, but not tied together as one.  Would you happen to know of any examples?

Comment: @anatolhiman I'll have to study into it further and tinker with it to see how it works.

Comment: @anatolhiman Honestly, it's strange that a store outside Vue ecosystem is recommended without a reason. It isn't coupled to Vue reactivity. Vuex does. As said, Vue already has everything to implement your own store, there's a bunch of articles like "you don't need Vuex".

Comment: @Optiq I'm not sure what the case looks like. You can use Vuex modules as micro stores, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @EstusFlask Honestly, that's a strange comment, knowing that DiffX is built on top of @vue/reactivity. You didn't bother looking at the project (it's noted in the readme). It also has a dedicated Vue version (https://github.com/jbjorge/diffx/tree/master/vue). And - I have successfully tested and used it in a large-scale Vue 3 project.

Comment: @anatolhiman Didn't notice that as it's framework-agnostic, good to know, I bookmarked it myself. Any way, I don't see reasons to promote it in Vuex question, unless it's known that Vuex doesn't fit the case (it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I solve that issue adding in the `main.js` this line: `window.Storyblok.vue.$store = store;`

Then in your plugin when you call the store use the same.
For example:
`window.Storyblok.vue.$store.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

So I am still learning StoryBlok and their plugin development, so please yell at me if this is wrong.

I was able to solve this like so.

Just for some context this is my general folder structure.

```
.
└── my-app/
    ├── node_module/
    │   └── ...
    ├── public/
    │   └── index.html
    └── src/
        ├── store/
        │   ├── state.js
        │   └── config.js
        ├── main.js
        └── Plugin.vue
```

**main.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
window.Storyblok.vue.use(Vuex); // This has to come before the Plugin import
import Plugin from './Plugin.vue'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {

  window.Fieldtype = Plugin

  let customComp = window.Storyblok.vue.extend(window.Fieldtype);
  window.Storyblok.vue.extend(window.Fieldtype);
  window.Storyblok.vue.component('custom-plugin', customComp);
  window.StoryblokPluginRegistered = true;

} else {

  let init = Plugin.methods.initWith()
  window.storyblok.field_types[init.plugin] = Plugin

}
```

**Plugin.vue**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import State from './store/state';

const store = new Vuex.Store(State);

export default {
  name: 'my-vue-plugin',

  mixins: [window.Storyblok.plugin],

  store: store,

  components: {},

  data() {
    return {}
  },
};
```

**state.js**

```
import Config from './config';

export default {
    modules: {
        Config
    },
    state: {
        count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        increment(state) {
            state.count++
        }
    }
};
```

Then anywhere in your nested components or whatever you can call the `increment` mutation like so `this.$store.commit('increment');`